# Making $\{0,\dots,9\}^2$ from smallest subset with coordinate-wise min and max

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, contest-math, integer-lattices

> (Iranian Combinatorics Olympiad-2020) Consider the set of $100$ ordered pairs $A = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), \dots, (9, 8), (9, 9)\}$.

> Given any subset $S$ of $A$, we have a device to append more elements to $S$. The device takes in two ordered pairs $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ from $S$, then appends the ordered pairs $(\min\{a, c\}, \min\{b, d\})$
> and $(\max\{a, c\}, \max\{b, d\})$ to $S$.

> From some initial $S$, your goal is to obtain $S=A$ using the device. Find the minimum size of $S$ for which this is possible.

I really don't have an idea on how to start. The shortest algorithm I found involved $18$ pairs in which we take pairs of form $(0,x)$ and $(y,0)$ where $x,y=1,2,\dots,9$. We can obtain $(x,y)$ from $(x,0)$ and $(y,0)$. But the answer is $10$ and I can't find a shorter algorithm to this.

Comment: I suggest:  work this out for smaller values.  The problem makes sense for any square...$1^2$ isn't interesting, but the answer isn't obvious for $2^2$ and certainly not for $3^2$ or $4^2$.

Comment: "We have a subset of these 100 cards..." -- which subset?

Comment: You may find it helps you to draw a $10 \times 10$ grid, rotated by $45$ degrees, and then think about what the output-points of the machine look like geometrically. (Secretly this is a question about finding a generating set for the lattice $\{0, \dotsc, 9\}^2$). @BenjaminWang, as I understand it the point is to find the smallest subset from which all cards can be generated.

Comment: Thanks @lulu and Izzak van Dongen. I've edited the question for clarity. Feel free to roll back (no disrespect to the Olympiad question writers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We remark that the machine can not produce any new values in either coordinate, all it does is the creation of new pairings.  Thus it can't be done with fewer than $10$.

To see that it can be done with $10$, note that it is easy to do it with the $19$ pairs $$\{(0,0), (1,0), \cdots, (9,0), (0,1), \cdots, (0,9)\}$$

so if you can generate that set, you are done.  Now consider the $10$ pairs $$\{(0,9), (1,8), (2,7), (3,6), (4,5), (5,4), (6,3), (7,2), (8,1), (9,0)\}$$

We can get the pair $(0,k)$ by applying the machine to $(0,9)$ and $(9-k, k)$.  Similarly we can get the pair $(k,0)$.

And we are done.

Comment: Nice answer - +1 :). A somewhat frivolous remark: you can get any pair $(a, b)$ in at most a single step. If $a + b < 9$ then $(a, b)$ is the minimum-output (meet) of $(a, 9 - a)$ and $(9 - b, b)$. If $a + b > 9$, then it's instead the maximum-output (join). PS: an inconsequential nitpick: I think there are $19$ of those pairs, right? Or $20$ if you count $(0, 0)$ twice.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen  Yeah, $19$.  No idea what I was thinking.  Thanks, will edit accordingly.